# facebook connect - get profile photo in high/original resolution

Tags: api, facebook

is there any way to get the profile photo of a users in a higher resolution than "large" which is 200x0...

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552/picture?type=large

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

I'have the same problem at the moment. My solution is to use the coverId of the profile album cover.

You can use GraphApi to get all Albums of the User

```
https://graph.facebook.com/%profileId%/albums
```

and use the coverId of the album with type 'profile' to get the profile photo

```
https://graph.facebook.com/%coverId%
```

Otherwise you can build a fql query like this

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner = %profileId% AND type = 'profile')
```

i found this in the facebook developer docs by writing the query for the answer

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

I hope this help you

Comment: This is a nice approach, but I just discovered that the cover of the profile album isn't necessarily the same as the currently selected profile image, it seems to be the most recently uploaded picture.

The profile album cover isn't updated if the user selects an old profile picture as their current profile image.